# How do I change the color of the hamburger menu icon?

Tags: android, hamburger-menu

First of all, I'd like to clarify that I'm willing to change the color of the Hamburger nav menu icon itself, and not the icons within the nav menu.

I followed this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#DrawerButton

As a result, I have a NavMenu Icon (Hamburger) within the app bar. Problem: The icon is black (the default color of the Vector drawable).

I created a new style:

```
<!-- Hamburger menu -->
<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/colorTextTitle</item>
</style>
```

I then added this style to my theme:

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Hamburger menu -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>
```

Made sure this style was the one used by my app in the manifest:

```
<application>
    android:theme="@style/customTheme"
</application>
```

And also applied this theme to the toolbar (just in case...)

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorToolbarBackground"
            app:theme="@style/customTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/customTheme"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextBody">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Result of the operation: None of this had any effect. The hamburger icon remains desperately black.

Would any of you be able to explain to me what mistake I made and how I can change this color?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you take a look at the sample provided by Google/Android Studio.

1. Create a new project called `test-hamburger` (name optional ;-) )
2. Select the "Drawer" template obviously. I didn't check "Use AndroidX" but should work.
3. I selected MinAPI 23/Target 28.

After you have the sample app, run it and observe toolbar is green and text/tint is white.

Open `values/styles.xml` (not the v21 version, f**c those) :)

This is how the existing theme looks:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

You need to add this line to it: 
`<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>`

And of course, define the style:

```
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>
```

All in all, your style should now look like:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Which, when run, looks like:

[image: Running]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I just did this, and it works. I then proceeded to do it again using API lvl 21 (the one I use in my project), and it still works (so at least I know that's not the problem).

I'll keep messing with this hamburger project, and try to find the proper way to implement my theme.

Comment: Make sure you use the right parent in your styles, it's very important: `parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle"`  is not the same as `parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this as the style of your toolbar

```
<style name="Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I hope it helps